# Wordpress portfolio how to change “ALL” category by one other category that I created?

Tags: categories

I'm looking for a solution to change the "All" category of the "Portfolio" part to another category that I created, is it possible?
Like this I display "my category 1" instead of "all categories".

Thank you in advance for your answers

different thing without achieving my ends

Comment: WP doesn't come with a Portfolio part, can you be more specific? Keep in mind nobody knows how your site is built or structured so you will need to explain this, and there are many wildly varying ways to build a portfolio in WordPress

Comment: I use the "BeTheme" theme in wordpress, which adds a portfolio system. There is a filter system that allows you to display only certain categories. In the filter there is "show all" which allows you to display all portfolios. What I'm looking to do is replace the URL of the "View All" button with another URL (of a particular category) which would allow me to never display all portfolios, only a particular category and then the following the selections the other categories.

Comment: ah, you need to go to BeTheme support, nobody here can help you without purchasing that theme and doing extensive investigation, 3rd party theme dev/user support questions are offtopic here.